# Percentage % padding that isn't relative to the parent

Tags: css, width, padding

I have this piece of HTML

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="box-header">
     <h4 class="box-header-title">CONTENT</h4>
   </div>
   <!-- rest of box -->
</div>
```

And I have this CSS:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 360px;
  position: relative;
}
.box-header {
  color: #fff;
}
.box-header-title {
  padding: 0 2%;
}
```

What I want: That the `.box.header-title` adjust it's padding according to the current width of `.box-header-title` instead of `.box`

Right now, if `.box` is `500px` computed value, the padding will be computed at `10px`. I want it to be computed at the current width of the element, instead of the parent box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CSS specification, percentage values for padding are computed based on the element's containing block (parent element).  So what you are seeing is the expected behavior.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

To get the result that you want, you would need to use some JavaScript or jQuery method to compute the desired value.

Comment: I can provide a jQuery solution later when I return to my desk.

Comment: hmm I see, so I need to apply the width manually on a parent wrapper so that the inner padding is correct, right?

Comment: Because you define `.box` to be inline-block, the width of `.box` will be computed as shrink-to-fit.  So the CSS parser cannot determine what the padding % will compute to unless you specify a fixed value for the width of `.box`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try,

**`position:absolute;`**

and give, appropriate, top and left values.